# Get column names into a new variable based on conditions

Tags: r, string, group-by

I have a data frame like this and I am doing this on R. My problems can be divided into two steps.

| SUBID | ABC | BCD | DEF |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 192838 | 4 | -3 | 2 |
| 193928 | -6 | -2 | 6 |
| 205829 | 4 | -5 | 9 |
| 201837 | 3 | 4 | 4 |

I want to make a new variable that contains a list of the column names that has a negative value for each SUBID. The output should look something like this:

| SUBID | ABC | BCD | DEF | output |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 192838 | 4 | -3 | 2 | "BCD" |
| 193928 | -6 | -2 | 6 | "ABC","BCD" |
| 205829 | 4 | -5 | 9 | "BCD" |
| 201837 | 3 | 4 | 4 | " " |

And then, in the second step, I would like to collapse the SUBID into a more general ID and get the number of unique strings from the output variable for each ID (I just need the number, the specific strings in the parenthesis are just for illustration).

| SUBID | output |
| --- | --- |
| 19 | 2 ("ABC","BCD") |
| 20 | 1 ("BCD") |

Those are the two steps that I thing should be done, but maybe there is a way that can skip the first step and goes to the second step directly that I don't know.
I would appreciate any help since right now I am not sure where to start on this. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- df %>% pivot_longer(-SUBID)

df1 <- df %>%
  group_by(SUBID) %>%
  summarise(output = paste(name[value < 0L], collapse = ','))

df2 <- df %>%
  group_by(SUBID = substr(SUBID, 1, 2)) %>%
  summarise(output_count = n_distinct(name[value < 0L]),
            output = paste0(output_count, ' (', paste(name[value < 0L], collapse = ','), ')'))
```

Outputs (two columns are created in the second case, one with just the count and another following your example):

```
df1

# A tibble: 4 x 2
   SUBID output   
   <int> <chr>    
1 192838 "BCD"    
2 193928 "ABC,BCD"
3 201837 ""       
4 205829 "BCD"    

df2

# A tibble: 2 x 3
  SUBID output_count output         
  <chr>        <int> <chr>          
1 19               2 2 (BCD,ABC,BCD)
2 20               1 1 (BCD)
```

Comment: Nice! I think OP was just looking for the count in the final, not the vector of values.

Comment: Thanks! I saw the comment now and modified.

Comment: What does `collapse` do? Btw your answer is much easier to understand so, thank you for that.

Comment: it's an argument to the function `paste()` and indicates the separator to use when merging a vector of strings into a single string. See `?paste` in Rstudio.

Comment: Indeed as @DanAdams explained. You could also use just e.g. `toString(name[value < 0L])` but `paste` with `collapse` gives more freedom with regards to the separator.

Answer (score 2):

This answers the first part of  your question, the second one, I didn't understand

```
 df$output <-apply(df[,-1], 1, function(x) paste(names(df)[-1][x<0], collapse = ","))
 df
   SUBID ABC BCD DEF  output
1 192838   4   3  -2     DEF
2 193928  -6  -2   6 ABC,BCD
3 205829   4  -5   9     BCD
4 201837   3   4   4
```

For the second part, try this:

```
id <- sapply(strsplit(sub("\\W+", "",  df$output), split = ""), function(x){
  sum(!(duplicated(x) | duplicated(x, fromLast = TRUE)))
} )


   data.frame(SUBID = substr(df$SUBID, 1,2), output = id, string = df$output)
      SUBID output  string
    1    19      3     DEF
    2    19      2 ABC,BCD
    3    20      3     BCD
    4    20      0
```

I added the variable `string` for you make sure  your count of unique values is ok.

Comment: Thank you! For the second part, what I wanted to do is to collapse the 6-digit subid into a 2-digit id based on the first two digits (19,20) and then get the number of unique strings in the output created in part 1. I have a typo in the original data of the question so that may have confused you.

Comment: Kindly add some explanation for what `apply`, `collapse`, `sapply` are doing.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to take advantage of [`dplyr::cur_data()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/context.html) to access the `names()` of the data and subset based on your criteria. Then you can take advantage of `tibble` list-columns to hold on to a set of column names of arbitrary length and finally calculate the number of unique values in that list.

```r
library(tidyverse)

d <- structure(list(SUBID = c(192838, 193928, 205829, 201837), ABC = c(4, -6, 4, 3), BCD = c(-3, -2, -5, 4), DEF = c(2, 6, 9, 4)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")

d %>% 
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(neg_col_names = list(names(cur_data())[cur_data() < 0])) %>% 
  group_by(ID_grp = str_sub(SUBID, 1, 2)) %>% 
  summarize(neg_col_count = n_distinct(unlist(c(neg_col_names))))

#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>   ID_grp neg_col_count
#>   <chr>          <int>
#> 1 19                 2
#> 2 20                 1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>